# Data structure for 1v1 table tennis matches. Vue, JS, Firebase/Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

Looking for any tips on how I might choose to store matches played from table-tennis in a web-application. I have written down a certain way I have it for now, and it works. I'm just wondering if anyone has good ideas on how to improve.

Currently my thought is to do is this way:

```js
matches: [
  {
    id: 1
    datePlayed: isoString
    player1: {playerId: 1, score: 10}
    player2: {playerId: 2, score: 8}
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this modeling is fine, I don't know if the data should be taken into account, but I suggest you be careful with these numeric ids.
Remembering that Firestore does not have native support for sequences, we usually use ids as a string.

In the latest version, it is possible to [count](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) the number of documents in a collection quickly and cheaply, but you would still have to take care to ensure that no two different users have the same id.

Comment: Thank you for the assurance. Don't worry about the content of the object. This was just dummy info. This was more about the structure in Firestore and in my app :D